# CFTs that are not modular invariant

Tags: conformal-field-theory, partition-function, wess-zumino-witten

Are there any 2d CFTs that do not have modular invariant partition functions? All the examples that I know of, like the free boson, WZW models, etc. have modular invariant partition functions.

Comment: You could take the compact free boson and NOT include the twisted sectors. That's a totally well defined CFT on the sphere but it cannot be defined on the torus.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course there are CFTs that exist on the sphere but not on higher genus Riemann surfaces.

To build an example, you can start with a modular invariant CFT, and consider a subset of fields that closes under OPEs. In the [Ising model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-dimensional_critical_Ising_model), this could be the identity, or the identity plus the energy operator. In the [compactified free boson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Massless_free_scalar_bosons_in_two_dimensions), you could take fields with zero winding (or even winding, etc).

Conversely, you can break modular invariance by adding extra fields to a modular invariant CFT. In the Ising model, you can add disorder operators.